is it safe to have C++ asserts in production code?
while asserts are a good way to test some expressions at runtime there is a possibility that application crashes at runtime. what should we do, should we avoid using asserts in C++ codes?

You should not use an assert for expected conditions.  If an assert trips for a never happen situation, your program is in a bad state.  Unrecoverable.  Broken axle.  Bugs are not recoverable errors.

assert doesn't do anything in release builds. To address your question about what you should do, it depends on what you want to happen when an error is detected. Decide what you want to happen first, that will determine what approach you want to take.

Typically assert is #defined to an empty statement for production builds. Which means assertion failures will not trigger SIGABRT.

assert is for mistakes you make (bugs), and exceptions are for mistakes the user makes.

I'd argue that crashing in release is fine. (Perhaps not by the means of assert.)

@HolyBlackCat but I think it is like shooting in your foots

Do you want the assert to cause a "crash" at runtime, or do you want it to produce the wrong result? assert(nukes_not_activated())?

Continuing with a broken program state is not better than crashing.

Assertions are a tool for development – you use them to assure a certain condition that during runtime always applies (or should). If one fails during testing, then you know your code is not correct and you have to rework it. In production code you assume the bugs being fixed and the condition always being met. In that case you don't want CPU times to be consumed for tests that won't fail anyway, thus they are skipped in release builds.

Semi-controversial opinion: asserts are practically useless, since you're going to have to handle anticipated errors gracefully in production anyway.

Think of an assert as an in-line local unit test to notice a never happen condition while exercising the code in a non-optimized debug build.

I have one macro in my logger that asserts on a critical error in debug mode. That has been very helpful in my debugging of new code that I have not yet written unit tests. In release mode it just logs the problem and lets other code decide if it warrants terminating the application after telling the user about the problem.

In production, you don't want your program to crash actually. So you shall not use assertions, your code needs to be fully tested before being released. Then, for the user errors, you have to handle them (for example with exceptions, etc...)

@Fareanor Ofcourse a program shouldn't crash. But I want my programs to crash even in production instead of having them limping on in an undefined state (and just making things progrssively worse). For the rest I agree, the code should have been unit-tested, integration tested  back to front and then some.

@PepijnKramer If you prefer your programme to crash even in production code then assertions are inappropriate; they get deactivated anyway (or would you rather release debug builds???). In such a case testing with classic if and throwing some exception is far better choice. If it appears too inconvenient then one might write one's own macro for...

@PepijnKramer But the world is not black and white. You are free to chose between a wrong program running in undefined state or a wrong program that crashes if you like. Personnally, I prefer another choice, which is a right program that doesn't crash, and that was the meaning of my comment. Hence the "fully-tested" mention :)

@Fareanor Haha yes ofcourse a fully deterministic, non-crashing program would be ideal  :)

@Aconcagua I really don't want debug builds in production, I am talking about releas build, so I am also not talking about asserts eiher. (They are hardly needed with enough unit test/code coverage). I am talking about crashing release builds, handle the exceptions you can. And if there is bugs due to programming errors (or UB) then crash (terminate) with a crash-dump for later analysis. As you know, in big projects, not all code will be under your personal control and mistakes will be made (even in your or my own code ;) )


What should we do?

assert is not intended for testing any arbitrary conditions at runtime! They are intended to assure conditions that during runtime always must be true. This is why asserts (usually) only are active in debug builds while they are entirely omitted in release builds.
Example:
// calculates a power of two
// throws on overflow
unsigned int powerOf2(unsigned int exponent);

void demo(unsigned int value)
{
    auto p2 = powerOf2(value);
    assert(p2 != 0);    // powers of 2 cannot be 0!
    assert(p2 > value); // powers of 2 are always greater than their logarithm
}

During development we test for these conditions as we expect some potential bugs might still be contained – most likely an overflow not having been detected – while the function promises to throw in that case.
In production code, in contrast, we assume that powerOf2 function works correctly – it would simply be a wast of CPU cycles to still leave these tests enabled.
Conditions that can be legally either met or not need to be tested by other means. Assume you do an integer division and ask the user for the divisor. Of course you need to test for zero even in production code. assert would now be totally inappropriate. If you can handle the case right in place, provide some appropriate error handling exactly there. If not, throw an exception. Main advantage of: that one you can catch at any level of the call stack while it is being unrolled – and potentially recover at a totally different location – or at least do some cleaning up like releasing any still open resources.
Side note: Proper unit-testing (at best automated by use of some appropriate framework) of powerOf2 in above example would make the asserts obsolete again – and typically is more precise/complete as well.

You should avoid using assert in your code.
What will assert do in release version?
Firstly, assert will not trigger SIGABRT in a release version. Here is a small piece of code from my Mac's C++ standard header file cassert:
#ifdef NDEBUG                  // This will be defined when code is in release version
#define assert(e) ((void)0)    // Which makes `assert` do nothing
#else
// assert will trigger SIGABRT
#endif

How to do something like assert in C++?
In real-life project development, a check before do anything may causes the program to crash, or is an illegal way to access memory, is a simple if-else. This is usually seen in pointer access:
int foo(int* bar) {
    if (bar == nullptr) {
        // Write log
        return -1;
    }

    // codes

    return 0;
}

Which is simple, but used everywhere. In real-life code development, stability is often more important. We usually won't hope the program to abort once there is a mistake.
If if-else still does not meet your requirements, maybe a try-catch will be needed.

safety-critical software is required to have multiple asserts in each and every function, you should be using asserts in your code, you just need to use them for their intended purpose, they catch bugs, not handle errors.

@AhmedAEK I do understand what you mean, but how about the solution of if-else + log I mentioned in my answer? I am working on a huge service development, so I think abort is might not the best solution

Actually, I very much like to keep asserts in release code. Here's why: an assert validates that something that must always be true is, in fact, always true. Except when it isn't. QA might have missed a case. With the assert still in place, the code will "crash", pointing to that assert. Bad. With the assert not in place, the code might run into a random crash later which is much more difficult to link to the assert-condition by support, or -- even worse -- it will just create jumbled data. Either way, removing the assert does not prevent that bug from showing up...

@ChristianStieber Fair enough, but we're talking about this under the assumption that assert won't work in the release version of the code. I don't mean to be judgement-I mean, how do you go about making sure assert works in your release code? I have a simple guess: implement your own assert that won't be affected by release macros?

@LiuYuan I'm actually trying to use the normal assert now. It's been rather trivial to make VisualStudio not set NDEBUG on release builds; I've not been able to do the same for the cmake that I use for Linux -- but since I'm very unhappy with cmake anyway, I'll remove it on the next opportunity and just make normal Makefiles that just work without all the hassle.

@ChristianStieber Thanks for the information. Just a suggestion, have you ever tried xmake? This is another compile util like cmake yet faster, easier and more readable for me. What's more important, it can export CMakeLists/Makefile from its own project file, even supports VS project and more. Maybe you can find it fit your hobbies as well. But I have not used it as real-life development yet, for there is already a customized compilation util. Yet in my personal development, it does suit my taste.

@ChristianStieber As for CMake NDEBUG problem, does this help? Default compile definition: how to get rid of those

@LiuYuan yeah, I stumbled across that one before. It starts with the usual crowd explaining how this is not a problem at all, then there's a guy saying to call replace on something, and finally there's a guy replacing the contents of a variable. Which sounded promising, but my attempt to set() this variable changed nothing.

@ChristianStieber Fine. I use CMake for little for it's syntax just hard to understand for me. Maybe try xmake I mentioned above?
